# Microsoft Word report issue using VB6

Tags: ms-word, vb6

[textPositionOFf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaTd3.png)   I'm building a report in VB6 to be printed in Microsoft Word. I'm seeing some issue that should otherwise not happen as I'm working with an already existing report. I'm basically working with a report that was created, and I'm making one of my own. I have a quick function that creates a header, where I pass parameters, mainly row number and text for the heading.

For the three lines of code applying Borders I'm getting an error that says "5941 - The requested member of the collection does not exist" I'm looking at the other report and it looks exactly as mine does yet i'm getting this error. Does anyone know what might be the issue?

```
Private Sub TableStyle_001_HeaderLine(row As Integer, Col1Txt As String)
  On Error GoTo error_handler:
  w_Doc.Tables.Add w_Rng, 1, 1

  w_Wrd.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
  With w_Wrd.Selection.Tables(w_DocTblIdx).Rows(row)
    With .Shading
        .Texture = wdTextureNone
        .ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray15
    End With
    With .Borders(wdBorderLeft)
        .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
        .Color = wdColorAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(wdBorderRight)
        .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
        .Color = wdColorAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(wdBorderTop)
        .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
        .Color = wdColorAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(wdBorderBottom)
        .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
        .Color = wdColorAutomatic
    End With

   .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone 'error here
   .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone 'here
   .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalUp).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone   'and here
   .Borders.Shadow = False

  'WRITE THE DATA
    .Cells(1).Select
    w_Wrd.Selection.Font.Bold = True
    w_Wrd.Selection.TypeText Col1Txt


  End With
```

Comment: But I have to wait 90 minutes :(

Comment: As you gain reputation, things will get better :-) The limitations are built  in to give newbies a chance to learn the guidelines and get acclimated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table doesn't have dialogonal lines in the cells, or the code targets an earlier version of Word that doesn't support diagonal lines, these lines of code are unnecessary. If this report is not being edited by anyone who could be adding diagonal lines to table cells, then comment the lines out with a note that they were in a different "incarnation" of reporting code but aren't necessary for the template this code is working on.